# Play ogg file in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play ogg files in android. I cannot find any useful documentation about this field in internet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void playSound()
{
    AudioManager meng = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int volume = meng.getStreamVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

    if (volume != 0)
    {
        if (_shootMP == null)
            _shootMP = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), Uri.parse("file:///system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg"));
        if (_shootMP != null)
            _shootMP.start();
    }
}
```